# Unable to loop more than 30 times in swift mailer

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer, bulk-email

I am trying to send bulk email using swift mailer I have to send 2500 emails at a time, unfortunately i cant sent more than 30 emails I use the following code

```
$sql = $db->Query("SELECT * FROM customer_data WHERE c_status=?", array("0"));
while($row=$db->FetchRow($sql)){

  $body="Test body";
  // Create a message
    $message = (new Swift_Message('test subject'))
      ->setFrom(['no_reply@xxx.com' => 'xxxx Group'])
      ->setTo([$row['c_email']])
      ->setBody($body, 'text/html')
      ;
    // Send the message
    $result = $mailer->send($message);

}
```

After 30 Emails i got an error like

> Fatal error: Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Expected response code
>   250 but got an empty response in
>   C:..\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:445
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:..\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(341):
>   Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->assertResponseCode('', Array)
>   1 C:..\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php(305):
>   Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('MAIL
>   FROM:executeCommand('DATA\r\n', Array,
>   Array) #3
>   C:..\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(497):
>   Swift_Transport_A in
>   C:..\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php
>   on line 445

any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Comment: create a cron function which call this function with additional parameter of id till mail sent .in your current function use that  parameter in query as limit and add next 25 records . change that parameter value inside function only. that cronjob needs to be set to execute after 5-10 min. this way it will work for you

Comment: no other way? @AlivetoDie

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj probably it's a limit set by the mailer host. In this case your code is ok.

Comment: I hope not. wait for sometime, maybe some-one will come with any-other approach

Comment: @TDK is there any possible way to change mailer time

Comment: Any particular reasin, wht its throwing an empty response? Is it timing out?

Comment: If thats the case, why dont you use messaging sysstem?

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj generally no